# My app crashes when starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I already searched the solution but my app still crashed when started a new activity. There's no error and I don't know what the problem. Hope you guys can teach and help me to solve this problem. I will post the logcat, androidmanifest.xml, mainactivity.class and main2activity.class so you can find where the thing goes wrong.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.user.betatesting;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1,b2;
    EditText ed1,ed2;

    TextView tx1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(ed1.getText().toString().equals("Luqman")&& ed2.getText().toString().equals("Kacax")){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ed2.setText("");
                ed1.setText("");
            }
        });
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MainActivity2.java

```
    package com.example.user.betatesting;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Handler;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String DEVICE_ADDRESS = "98:D3:31:90:82:9A"; //MAC Address of Bluetooth Module
    private final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private InputStream inputStream;

    Thread thread;
    byte buffer[];

    boolean stopThread;
    boolean connected = false;
    String command;

    Button lock_state_btn, bluetooth_connect_btn;

    TextView lock_state_text;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lock_state_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lock_state_btn);
        bluetooth_connect_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_connect_btn);

        lock_state_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lock_state_text);



        bluetooth_connect_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                if(BTinit())
                {
                    BTconnect();
                    beginListenForData();

                    // The code below sends the number 3 to the Arduino asking it to send the current state of the door lock so the lock state icon can be updated accordingly

                    command = "3";

                    try
                    {
                        outputStream.write(command.getBytes());
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        lock_state_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                if(connected == false)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please establish a connection with the bluetooth servo door lock first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    command = "1";

                    try
                    {
                        outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); // Sends the number 1 to the Arduino. For a detailed look at how the resulting command is handled, please see the Arduino Source Code
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void beginListenForData() // begins listening for any incoming data from the Arduino
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        stopThread = false;
        buffer = new byte[1024];

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int byteCount = inputStream.available();

                        if(byteCount > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
                            inputStream.read(rawBytes);
                            final String string = new String(rawBytes, "UTF-8");

                            handler.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    if(string.equals("3"))
                                    {
                                        lock_state_text.setText("Lock State: LOCKED"); // Changes the lock state text

                                    }
                                    else if(string.equals("4"))
                                    {
                                        lock_state_text.setText("Lock State: UNLOCKED");

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopThread = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    //Initializes bluetooth module
    public boolean BTinit()
    {
        boolean found = false;

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(bluetoothAdapter == null) //Checks if the device supports bluetooth
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device doesn't support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) //Checks if bluetooth is enabled. If not, the program will ask permission from the user to enable it
        {
            Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter,0);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if(bondedDevices.isEmpty()) //Checks for paired bluetooth devices
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please pair the device first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice iterator : bondedDevices)
            {
                if(iterator.getAddress().equals(DEVICE_ADDRESS))
                {
                    device = iterator;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    public boolean BTconnect()
    {

        try
        {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(PORT_UUID); //Creates a socket to handle the outgoing connection
            socket.connect();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Connection to bluetooth device successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            connected = true;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        }

        if(connected)
        {
            try
            {
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream(); //gets the output stream of the socket
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try
            {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream(); //gets the input stream of the socket
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return connected;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

And the Logcat

```
02-15 22:14:23.340 11317-11317/com.example.user.betatesting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.user.betatesting, PID: 11317
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.betatesting/com.example.user.betatesting.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.user.betatesting.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:59)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6864)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: Why you are using `activity_main` layout in both `Activity`. Where's the layout for `MainActivity2` ?

Comment: you using same layout for both Activity make sure you attaching correct layout to Activity .Post your Main2Activity xml code

Comment: Thanks guys.The problem is I using the same layout in both Activity. I changed the layout and the app working.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from line 59 of your MainActivity2 file. This is because the `bluetooth_connect_btn` is null.

This is most likely because there is not a button with the id `R.id.bluetooth_connect_btn` in your xml layout file.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because compiler unable to find button component with this id. So please check activity layout.